# Grails/Hibernate How to untangle the no-session-opened exception caused by storing object in http session

Tags: hibernate, session, grails

I know that storing object in http session is a bad idea since OSIV cannot resolve the LazyInitializationException caused when I try to access to a collection type property of this object.

**Unfortunately, i have been storing some objects in the http session, the currentUser for example** :

I store the current user in the http session like :

```
session.currentUser = loggedUser
```

An user has a rules collection like

```
session.currentUser.rules
```

As expected, when i try to access to the rules collection in the subsequent requests, i get a LazyInitializationException exception since session.currentUser lose it's persistence context.

**Even though i'am migrating to the correct approch that is storing the objects'id in http session,  i have to find a solution for ensuring that the access to collection property of the objects stored in http session don't casue LazyInitializationException.**

I am thinking about a solution by overriding a method of HttpSession:

```
HttpSession.metaClass.getProperty { name ->
        if(name.equals("currentUser")){
            def userId = delegate.getProperty(name).id
            def userInstance = Utilisateur.get(userId)
            println 'in metaclass currentUser ' + userInstance.isAttached()
            return userInstance
        }else{
            return  delegate.getProperty(name)
        }
    }
```

**instead of returning directly the currentUser, i retrieve an attached object from hibernate session by using Get() method**.

this solution seems working,
do you think it's a good idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to make the `rules` association non-lazy

```
static mapping = {
  rules lazy:false
}
```

which will load all the rules for a user up-front when the user is loaded, so no need to refer back to the hibernate session later.

Comment: hello Roberts, but i still want to have a lazy fetch mode .

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you object is full initialised prior to placing it into the session. The best way to do this is to ensure you query eagerly. So for example if you `User` has `rules` you would do:

```
session.currentUser = User.findByLogin("blah", [fetch:[rules:"eager"])
```

Comment: hello rocher, thanks for replying. but do you think my solution will work fine (overrid getProperty() of the HttpSession class) ?

Comment: another question : Is that an eager finder (User.findByLogin("blah", [fetch:[rules:"eager"])) is equivelent to Hibernate.initialize(usr.rules) ? thanks